# Find the line number a string is on in an external text file

Tags: python, file, text, external

I am trying to create a program where it gets input from a string entered by the user and searches for that string in a text file and prints out the line number. If the string is not in the text file, it will print that out. How would I do this? Also I am not sure if even the for loop that I have so far would work for this so any suggestions / help would be great :).

What I have so far:

```
file = open('test.txt', 'r')
string = input("Enter string to search")
for string in file:
    print("") #print the line number
```

Comment: Will the `string` match the `line` exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A text file differs from memory used in programs (such as dictionaries and arrays) in the manner that it is sequential. Much like the old tapes used for storage a long, long time ago, there's no way to grab/find a specific line without combing through all prior lines (or somehow guessing the exact memory location). Your best option is just to create a for loop that iterates through each line until it finds the one it's looking for, returning the amount of lines traversed until that point.

```
file = open('test.txt', 'r')
string = input("Enter string to search")
lineCount = 0
for line in file:
    lineCount += 1
    if string == line.rstrip(): # remove trailing newline
        print(lineCount)
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implement this algorithm:

- Initialize a counter
- Read lines one by one
- If the line matches the target, return the current count
- Increment the count
- If reached the end without returning, the line is not in the file

For example:

```
def find_line(path, target):
    with open(path) as fh:
        count = 1
        for line in fh:
            if line.strip() == target:
                return count
            count += 1

    return 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
filepath = 'test.txt'
substring = "aaa"
with open(filepath) as fp:  
   line = fp.readline()
   cnt = 1
   flag = False
   while line:
       if substring in line:
            print("string found in line {}".format(cnt))
            flag = True
            break
       line = fp.readline()
       cnt += 1
   if not flag:
       print("string not found in file")
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `string` will match a `line` exactly, we can do this in `one-line`:

```
print(open('test.txt').read().split("\n").index(input("Enter string to search")))
```

Well the above kind of works accept it won't `print` "no match" if there isn't one. For that, we can just add a little `try`:

```
try:
    print(open('test.txt').read().split("\n").index(input("Enter string to search")))
except ValueError:
    print("no match")
```

---

Otherwise, if the `string` is just somewhere *in* one of the `lines`, we can do:

```
string = input("Enter string to search")
for i, l in enumerate(open('test.txt').read().split("\n")):
    if string in l:
        print("Line number", i)
        break
else:
    print("no match")
```